# Set up separate stores with different quantities of the same items

Tags: magento

I have 4 stores with different stores with some similar and some different products.

I want different inventory for all stores, I tried to add the inventory of stores it changes Globally, I'm using the below code.

```
$sku='123asd';
$qty=12;
$exitProduct = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')->getIdBySku((string)$sku); 

                if($exitProduct)
                {

                        $product =Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($exitProduct);
                            $product->setStoreId(2)->setPrice($xmlDatas['preco'])->save();

                        $productId = $product->getId();
                        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
                        $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
                        $stockItem->setData('qty', (integer) $qty]);
                        $stockItem->save();
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
```

**How can I set different Qty for different stores?**

Comment: You can try this https://www.wyomind.com/advanced-inventory-magento.html

Answer (score 0):

If you will create second website then You can manage product qty easily without install any extension. just create second website and set store and store view whithin it.

Comment: No, its not possible, qty attribute is global in scope. How can you do this? please explain